# Make a progress bar inside a button

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
document.querySelector('button[id="But_wood"]').addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.classList.add("active");
    setTimeout(()=>{
        this.classList.remove("active");
    },2000);
});
```

```css
.Collect {
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 120px;
  height: 30px;
  color: #000000;
  display: inline;
  font: normal normal 16px/25px "alegreya", serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.Collect.active {
  background: lime;
}

.Collect.active::before {
  animation: 2s slidein linear;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 5px;
  width: 120px;
  background: #fa237d;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

@keyframes slidein {
  from {
    transform: scaleX(1);
  }

  to {
    transform: scaleX(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<button class="Collect" id="But_wood">Pick wood</button>
```

I want to have a progress bar running inside a button when the user clic on it. Despite several tweaking of the CSS, none of them made it work and no similar post has given me an answer either...

Despite several tweaking of the CSS, none of them made it work and no similar post has given me an answer either...

I would like for the progress bar to be inside the button, under the text. On a side note, I didn't manage to make it run from left to right, but only expending on both side at the same time, how can I change that too ?

https://jsfiddle.net/dmv0obpu/57/

Thank you !

html :

```
<button class="Collect" id="But_wood">Pick wood</button>
```

CSS :

```
.Collect {
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 120px;
  height: 30px;
  color: #000000;
  display: inline;
  font: normal normal 16px/25px "alegreya", serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.Collect.active {
  background: lime;
}

.Collect.active::before {
  animation: 2s slidein linear;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 5px;
  width: 120px;
  background: #fa237d;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

@keyframes slidein {
  from {
    transform: scaleX(1);
  }

  to {
    transform: scaleX(0);
  }
}
```

JS :

```
document.querySelector('button[id="But_wood"]').addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.classList.add("active");
    setTimeout(()=>{
        this.classList.remove("active");
    },2000);
});
```

Comment: When you set your `.Collect.active::before` to position absolute, you also need to specify `top`/`bottom`/`left`/`right` to set the **position** of your element. The parent `.Collect` also need to set `position: relative` to reset the position reference for its children.

Comment: Ah ! Thank you ! That helped me position the progress bar. Any idea why it progress on both side at the sime time ?

Comment: @Saelys You can set `transform-origin: left bottom;` in `.Collect.active::before {` (and you probably want to swap your slidein keyframe 0 and 1)

Comment: Worked like a charm, even without swaping, thank you !